# Как найти изменение к последнему дню прошлой недели?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, обработка-данных

Найти разницу `Weekly_ch` между текущим значением `Sales` и значением `Sales` в последний известный день прошлой недели. Количество данных за каждую неделю разное. Некоторых недель нет.

Через `for`, конечно получилось, а как сделать красиво через `groupby()` или что-то похожее?

[Ссылка на csv с данными](https://yadi.sk/d/mCY9-QE5OOsXKQ) и наглядный пример:

[image: Даты, Продажи и Изменения к последнему известному дню прошлой недели]

Comment: Воспроизводимый пример исходных данных добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog добавлено

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

```
df["res"]= df["Sales"] - \
     df.assign(x=df["Sales"].shift())
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="W"))
       ["x"]
       .transform("first")
```

результат:

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
         Date  Sales  Weekly_ch    res
0  2021-04-01    100        NaN    0.0
1  2021-04-02    200        NaN  100.0
2  2021-04-05    400      200.0  200.0
3  2021-04-06    500      300.0  300.0
4  2021-04-07    600      400.0  400.0
5  2021-04-08    700      500.0  500.0
6  2021-04-09    800      600.0  600.0
7  2021-04-10    900      700.0  700.0
8  2021-04-11   1000      800.0  800.0
9  2021-04-19    200     -800.0 -800.0
10 2021-04-20    200     -800.0 -800.0
11 2021-04-23    400     -600.0 -600.0
12 2021-04-24    500     -500.0 -500.0
```

NOTE: в данном решении не совсем правильно расчитываются данные за первую неделю. С этим еще придется поработать.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых -  ваш набор данных не всем доступен. Да и зачем он всем? Почему бы вам не привести   воспроизводимый пример -  т.е. хотя бы данные, а еще лучше -  готовый DataFrame, на которых можно было бы проверить предлагаемы вам инструмент (кому интересно руками набивать ваши данные). Поэтому даю просто наводку а не решение.

Если вам хочется использовать groupby() то:
Последний элемент в группе можно найти с помощью конструкции

```
df.loc[df.groupby('......').date.idxmax()]
```

или так:

```
df.groupby('....').tail(1)
```

Если вы хотите сгруппировать по неделям, то проще это сделать не через groupby, а с помощью конструкции

```
df.resample('W')
```

А еще можно группировать вот так:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="1W"))
```

Не знаю, что вам подойдет больше. Поэтому дальше - сами соединяйте в зависимости от того, что вам конкретно надо и проверяйте на своих данных.